# Does any version of Angular Js supports Firefox 1.7.13?

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, firefox, web

I have developed application in Angular Js 1.3.16 and it is working fine with latest version of chrome and Firefox.

But now i need to run this application in Firefox 1.7.35 in some old system and it does not work.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! That's an interesting problem, I think that browser pre-dates even the first versions of AngularJS. Do you get any specific errors?